# redirect vs rewrite?

Tags: web, websphere

I'm trying configuring sunone webserver 6.1 config file `obj.conf`

What I want is:

1. I request `http://www.test.com/aaa/a.htm`
2. and I receive `http://www.test.com/bbb/b.htm`

I config `obj.conf` like this

`NameTrans fn="redirect" from="/aaa/a.htm" url="http://www.test.com/bbb/b.htm"`

That does work but internet browser address bar change from `a.htm` to `b.htm`

I want address bar not change.

If I try rewrite attribute, address will not change? and Is there a way using rewrite attribute on Sunone webserver or That is only possible with was server.

First of all What is redirect, rewrite?

Answer (score 1):

**Redirect** is a 301 error that means that the page does not exist anymore and will redirect to a different page *( changes url as well )* 
**Rewrite** is just a shadow URL that can be used to call in a different URL *( does not change url )*

[How do I get sun webserver to redirect from /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295/how-do-i-get-sun-webserver-to-redirect-from)

Comment: Dont forget to check it off as your answer :)

Comment: I checked it out. just my typing slow. unnderstand me thank you

Comment: Try this http://2nd.narastat.kr/aaa/a.htm This will change browser address bar and I used redirect attribute. I want no change. Including sunone webserver, webserver does have rewrite attribute? If not, Do I have to use was server

Comment: Thank you for your answer
and please use esay english
I don't speak, write english well


Is that right redirect is error?
what? error? I can not understand

and what's the meaning shadow url?
I've never heard of shadow url


thank you

Comment: [3xx status codes aren't errors, they're just redirects (not limited to 301).](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3)